# Linux From Scratch - Error: sed: can't read /tools/lib/libstdc++.la: No such file or directory

Tags: linux

I'm trying to use a [Docker configuration to run Linux From Scratch](https://github.com/reinterpretcat/lfs). But I'm getting an error `sed: can't read /tools/lib/libstdc++.la: No such file or directory`.

It looks like after looking at the Docker configuration repo the line that is failing is `sed 's/tools/usr/' /tools/lib/libstdc++.la > /usr/lib/libstdc++.la` (line 9 of lfs/scripts/build/6.6-create-essentials.sh).

What is strange is I can't find any documentation or reference to this in the [actual Linux From Scratch book](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/). So I'm not sure what the purpose of that line is, which makes it more difficult to debug and try to fix.

Possibly it was something that was added to make it work with Docker? Any ideas on how to fix this error?